# ReactJS app doesn't render using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm trying to create an app that has a homepage and an about page. I want to be able to switch between the two pages by clicking on the respective anchor/link in the navigation bar.
Everything was rendering fine before adding the `BrowserRouter` and the related elements to my code, but now nothing renders on the web page.
The version of `react-router-dom` I'm using is `react-router-dom@6.2.1`.

Here is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

`App.js` that makes use of a Bootstrap example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./About";


export default function App() {
    return (
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <Link class="navbar-brand" to="/"><i class="bi bi-yin-yang"></i></Link>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to="/about">About Us</Link>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>

</div>
);
};
```

And here is the `About.js` file:

```
import { Fragment } from "react";

export default function About() {
    return (
<Fragment>
    
    <h1>About Us</h1>

</Fragment>
);
};
```

And, finally, the `Home.js` file:

```
import { Fragment } from "react";

export default function About() {
    return (
<Fragment>
    
    <h1>Home</h1>

</Fragment>
);
};
```

I tried to follow a few guides on routing with ReactJS and searching for other answers, but with no success. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check the order of the routes that you've declared on <Routes>. The most specific always goes at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling App inside the router with the route `/` result in sort of an infinite loop.

your router should be like this

```js
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

dont forget to renanme the function name of your home component

```
import { Fragment } from "react";

export default function Home() {
    return (
<Fragment>
    
    <h1>Home</h1>

</Fragment>
);
};
```

It could be a nice add to get your nav in a dedicated component.

Comment: I've changed the `App` component to `Home` for the "/" path, but still, nothing renders.

Comment: I've solved it, I just needed to restart the application after applying the changes you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The links should be moved *into* the router so it can know to update the route being matched & rendered. You only need one router per app to provide a routing context, so ensure you've no other routers rendered elsewhere in your app.

You should also fix the component being rendered on your home `"/"` path, i.e. it should probably be `Home` instead of recursively rendering `App` again.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <Link class="navbar-brand" to="/">
            <i class="bi bi-yin-yang"></i>
          </Link>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <Link class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <Link class="nav-link" to="/about">
                  About Us
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've changed the `App` component to `Home` for the "/" path and moved the navbar into the `BrowserRouter`, but still, nothing renders.

Comment: I've solved it, I just needed to restart the application after applying the changes you suggested. Thank you!